# Force active on active tab

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs

I have a set of `jquery-ui` tabs, the content of which is loaded via ajax. I would like to be able to force (somehow) the `active` option to work even if the tab is currently active (for refresh purposes).

Doing something like this: `$('#'+tab_group_id).tabs('option', 'active', tab.index());`

After reading [this](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8735#comment:26) thread, it looks like if the tab is already active, trying to activate it does nothing. How can I achieved the desired behavior of "forcing" an activate?